# React redux can not get the dispatch right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a call that changes redux state but i am having problems with dispatching the action. I am sure all imports are correct. I think the main problem is in mapStateToProps but just cant seem to find it.

**Call**

```
 onClick={() => this.props.ethereum}
```

**mapStateToProps and other...**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return({
    depositMenu: state.depositMenu
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return ( {
    visa: () => dispatch(visa()),
    bitcoin: () => dispatch(bitcoin()),
    ethereum: () => dispatch(ethereum())
  })
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps
)(Deposit)
```

**Actions**

```
export const visa= () => {
    return {
        type: 'VISA'
    }
}

export const bitcoin = () => {
    return {
        type: 'BITCOIN'
    }
}

export const ethereum = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ETHEREUM'
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const MainPageDeposit = (state = 'visa', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'VISA':
            return state = 'visa';
        case 'ETHEREUM':
            return state = 'ethereum';
        case 'BITCOIN':
            return state = 'bitcoin';
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default MainPageDeposit;
```

**And combine reducers**

```
import MainPageDeposit from './MainPageDeposit';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    depositMenu: MainPageDeposit,
})

export default allReducers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change `onClick={() => this.props.ethereum}` to `onClick={this.props.ethereum}`